# structure bit field data manipulation using for loop

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

Using structure a character variable is declared. I want to access(read and write) all the bit of that character type variable. I have solved that in my way using Bit Field. The code is given below. But if i want to print them they should be called individually. I am unable to call them in a loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct SevenSegmentValue
{
  unsigned char bit0:1;
  unsigned char bit1:1;
  unsigned char bit2:1;
};

struct SevenSegmentValue abc[3]={{1,0,1},{0,1,1},{1,1,0}};

int main(void)
{
    printf( "Memory size occupied by status1 : %d\n", sizeof(abc));
    printf( "Memory size occupied by status1 : %d\n", abc[2].bit0);
    printf( "Memory size occupied by status1 : %d\n", abc[2].bit1);
    printf( "Memory size occupied by status1 : %d\n", abc[2].bit2);
}
```

Comment: C or C++? The two don't always agree on program semantics. You shouldn't tag "just because".

Comment: Why the tag `c++`

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an array of bit fields, so you can't loop through them.

If you want to print all the bit in an `unsigned char`, you can use bit shifting to access each bit:

```
unsigned char c = 0x32;
int i;
for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
    printf("bit %d: %d\n", i, ((c >> i) & 1));
}
```

Output:

```
bit 0: 0
bit 1: 1
bit 2: 0
bit 3: 0
bit 4: 1
bit 5: 1
bit 6: 0
bit 7: 0
```

Note that this print the least significant bit first.  If you want the most significant bit first, have the loop count down instead of up.

Comment: Can u do that using my code??? because i can't do that using my code....